# Django: the detail page is not showing(template error)

Tags: python, django

am working on a Django project where showing the details of post and amount 
here is my models.py of post

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("Loader:my_job", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

this is my second models which I inherit  Loader post

```
class price(models.Model):
    my_post = models.ForeignKey(Loader_post, related_name='prices',on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     null=True, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, default='')
    driver_price = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    approved_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("Driver:Driverview")

def __str__(self):
    return self.driver_price
```

this is the view.py of both list and details view

```
class offer_view(ListView, SelectRelatedMixin):
    context_object_name = 'offern'
    model = Loader_post
    template_name = "offer.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Loader_post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return qs


class offer_view_detail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'offernew'
    model = Loader_post
    template_name = "offer_detail.html"
```

here is my HTML page of list view ...when someone clicks on it it shows the detail of next post
offer.html

```
{% for my in offern %}
<a href="{{my.id}}/">{{my.sender_name}}</a> {% endfor %}
```

and when someone clicks on its route to the detail page .. but it shows template doesn't exist
this is my detail page ie. offer_details.hml

```
<p>{{offernew.sender_name}}</p>
<p>{{offernew.receiver_name}}</p>
 {% for x in offernew.prices.all %}
<p>
<p>{{x.driver_name}}</p>
</p>
```

and this is urls.py

```
path('offerdetail/<int:pk>', views.offer_view_detail.as_view(),name="offerdetail"),
path('offer/', views.offer_view.as_view(), name="offer"),
```

Comment: change to  `<a href="{% url 'offerdetail' pk=my.id %}">{{my.sender_name}}</a>`in your list view template.

Comment: its is working but I need details from price model also....it is not inheriting

Answer (score 0):

Following on from comments,

In you ListView,

```
<a href="{{my.id}}/">{{my.sender_name}}</a>
```

here, the url specified is not defined in your `urls.py`, that's why it was showing no `template doesn't exist`, changing to this would solve this.

```
<a href="{% url 'offerdetail' pk=my.id %}">{{my.sender_name}}</a>
```

Now, To show prices model in your DetailView, i would do something like this.

```
class offer_view_detail(DetailView):
   context_object_name='offernew'
   model = Loader_post
   template_name = "offer_detail.html"

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['price_model'] = self.object.prices.all()
       return context
```

and In your Template

```
<p>{{offernew.sender_name}}</p>
<p>{{offernew.receiver_name}}</p>
    {% for x in offernew.price_model %}
        <p>{{x.driver_name}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

[Django Docs for DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

Comment: thanks for ur help sir but again price model are not inheriting

Comment: @dilmeetpadda, can you put this `{{ offernew.price_model }}` in your template and check what you get,

Comment: sorry my mistake, can you try this: `<p>{{offernew.sender_name}}</p>
<p>{{offernew.receiver_name}}</p>
    {% for x in offernew.price_model %}
        <p>{{x.driver_name}}</p>
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: sir nothing happens

Comment: please share what you get by this. `{{ offernew.price_model }}`

Comment: only show sender_name and receiver name ...related to loader_post model...

Comment: please paste the that reponse.here.

Comment: bhuoij

Diljeet Singh